# Is the reaction of silver nitrate and copper endothermic or exothermic?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, enthalpy

> Is the following reaction endothermic or exothermic and why?
> $$\ce{2 AgNO3(aq) + Cu(s) -> Cu(NO3)2(aq) + 2 Ag(s)}$$

I have a feeling that it is exothermic due to the fact that it is spontaneous and will end in around 30 minutes (which I am guessing is because it will run out of energy to burn) and no source of energy is there for it to gain energy from, but is this right?

I found on the internet, that I was right about the reaction being exothermic as $\Delta_rH^\circ= \pu{-147.39 kJ}$, but my real question is why? Is its spontaneity the only means of support for this answer?

Comment: Hi and welcome to chemistry.stackexchange.com. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. I improved the formatting of your post by adding MathJax. For more information on how to do so yourself, check out the [help], [this meta-post](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86) or [this one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/444). Note that your question can be considered [tag:homework], and as per our [homework policy](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/141), we require you to show your thoughts and work to prevent it getting closed. Please [edit] the post accordingly.

Comment: You're basically saying that it's exothermic because it happens which of course isn't true.

Comment: Many endothermic reactions are spontaneous as well.

Answer (score 3):

You may already know that the world is not about enthalpy but about Gibbs free energy. A reaction is sponanteous if the change Gibbs free energy is negative.

$$\Delta G = \Delta H - T \cdot \Delta S$$

As you see, enthalpy and entropy play into this. Looking at your reaction, we note that we are taking two ions out of a solution to release one into solution. Compare the following, slightly different description:

$$\ce{2 Ag+ (aq) + Cu (s) <=>> 2 Ag (s) + Cu^2+ (aq)}$$

From an entropic point of view, this is bad. Rather than having two dissolved ions, we have one on the products’ side. Therefore, we can assume $\Delta S < 0$, therefore $T \cdot \Delta S < 0$. Negating it gives a positive value.

But the reaction *is* spontaneous, so $\Delta G < 0$. This can only be true if $\Delta H$ is sufficiently negative to counteract the loss of entropy. Thus we conclude that $\Delta H < 0$ and the reaction is exothermic.

Answer (score 0):

I have carried out the experiment myself and from observation, the reaction is exothermic (releases heat) even though I didn't quantitatively determine the value of heat change occurred.

Comment: If you didn’t quantitatively determine the heat released, how can you be sure that the reaction is exothermic? As it stands, this answer needs additional references …